# FirebaseInstanceIdService does not get called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the examples on the internet and reviewed many questions here and on other websites

I built my application so it handles FCM Notifications, but I still cant find out why FirebaseInstanceIdService does not get called.

I declared it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".InstanceService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".MessageService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My Service is

```
public class InstanceService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String REG_Token="REG_Token";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String recent_token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); // get token from the server

        Log.d(REG_Token,recent_token); // show device token in Logcat View

    }
```

I look at Logcat but there is no REG_Token there.

I tried to debug the code and stopped it at `Log.d(REG_Token,recent_token);`, but it did not stop there.

I think the service is not called at all and I can't find out why.

Comment: I had some problems as well with registering, I found that the first time you need it 2 times, I don't know why, (this was a couple of months ago), try caling it 2 times

Comment: Did u add internet permission in your manifest??

Comment: try adding super.onTokenRefresh();

Comment: is your <service> defined in the <application> tag?

Comment: I have Internet Permission. and Yes my service is in application tag

Comment: have yoy tried by adding super.onTokenRefresh();  ??

Comment: where to add super.onTokenRefresh();  ?

Comment: Do you have any activities in your app? Did you start the app after installing on the device (or emulator)?

Comment: Yes I do have an activity on my app. I started the app on both real device and emulator

Comment: Likely the token has already been generated, which means `onTokenRefresh()` won't get called. Can you add `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` to your main activity's `onCreate`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=en#sample-register)

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

It means that the `onTokenRefresh()` method is not called every time the app is opened but only when one of those 4 events occurred.

The simplest way is to uninstall the app and then install the app again. After it's installed, open the app and then look at the logcat (based on your code).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I uninstalled then run the app again. yet no REG_Token

Comment: are you sure that the logcat filter is on Debug or Verbose? @asmgx

Comment: I used Logcat, I also used the debug to stop the code at Log.d(REG_Token,recent_token); but never reached it

Comment: And you run the debugging mode after the app is uninstalled? that's weird.
Have you tried running the app on a real physical device?

Comment: I did not use a real device, just the emulator

Comment: Well, looks like the instance id only works on real device, not sure why. Try running your app on a real device and then check the logcat

Comment: I tried it now on a real device, still the same no REG_Token

Comment: @asmgx I'm getting the same problem. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and still no sign of the REG_TOKEN in the Logcat... Does anyone know the correct solution to this?